# On Item click on each of the Item In a recycler view, I want to replace fragments inside viewpager2

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, replace, android-viewpager

I have **MyViewPager2** adapter with four Fragments and a **SemesterFragment** that contain recyclerview on it **DepartmentRVAdapter**. onItem click in the recycler view i want to move to the respective fragment in viewpager2

---

How can i achieve the below description?

- (onItem click on *0* pos) computer science department --->then load fragments(sem1,sem2,sem3,sem4) in a viewpager2 ***else if***
- (onItem click on *1* pos) statistic department --->then load fragments(sem1,sem2,sem3,sem4) in a viewpager2
- e.t.c

below Is what I have, the code Is more focused now.Thanks

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout,new DepartmentFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

DepartmentFragment.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DepartmentFragment extends Fragment implements ClickInterface {
    List<DepartmentModel> mData;
    DepartmentRVAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public DepartmentFragment() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start,container,false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapter = new DepartmentRVAdapter(mData,getContext(),this, DepartmentFragment.this);

//list of departments in the school
        mData.add(new DepartmentModel("Computer Science",R.drawable.glogo));
        mData.add(new DepartmentModel("Statistic",R.drawable.horse));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    //here implement interface class methods
    @Override
    public void onItemClickListener(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"clicked " + mData.get(position).getDepName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemLongClickListener(int position) {

    }
}
```

DepartmentRVAdapter.Java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DepartmentRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DepartmentRVAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<DepartmentModel> mData;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    ClickInterface clickInterface;
    DepartmentFragment schoolFragment;

    public DepartmentRVAdapter(List<DepartmentModel> mData, Context context, ClickInterface clickInterface, DepartmentFragment sf) {
        this.mData=mData;
        this.context=context;
        this.clickInterface=clickInterface;
        schoolFragment =sf;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_department_xml,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imgDepLogo.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getDepLogo());
        holder.tvDepName.setText(mData.get(position).getDepName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imgDepLogo;
        TextView tvDepName;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgDepLogo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDeptLogo);
            tvDepName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDepName);

            tvDepName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   clickInterface.onItemClickListener(getLayoutPosition());

                 switch (getAdapterPosition()){
                        //loads department best on the position that user click
                        case 0:
                        // it loads all departments in the school
                          Objects.requireNonNull(schoolFragment.getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                                  .beginTransaction()
//                                  .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.exit_to_right)
                                  .replace(R.id.frameLayout,new SemesterFragment())
                                  .addToBackStack(null).
                                  commit();
                            break;
                            case 1:
                            // it loads all departments in the school
                                Objects.requireNonNull(schoolFragment.getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                                        .beginTransaction()
                                       // .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.exit_to_left,R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_left)
                                        .replace(R.id.frameLayout,new SemesterFragment())
                                        .addToBackStack(null).
                                        commit();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

SemesterFragment.Java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;

public class SemesterFragment extends Fragment{
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    MyViewPager2 adapter;

    public SemesterFragment() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_semester, container, false);
        viewPager2 = (ViewPager2) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        adapter = new MyViewPager2(getChildFragmentManager(),this.getLifecycle());

        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2,
                new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                        tab.setText("Sem" + (position + 1));
                    }
                }).attach();
        return view;
    }
}
```

RVFragment.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class RVFragment extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVFragment.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
List<SemesterModelClass> mData;

    public RVFragment(Context context, List<SemesterModelClass> mData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roww_xml,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvCourseCode.setText(mData.get(position).getCourseCode());
        holder.tvCourseTitle.setText(mData.get(position).getCourseTitle());
        holder.tvCreditUnit.setText(mData.get(position).getCreditUnit());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvCourseCode;
        TextView tvCourseTitle;
        TextView tvCreditUnit;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvCourseCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCourseCode);
            tvCourseTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCourseTitle);
            tvCreditUnit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCreditUnit);
        }
    }
}
```

MyViewPager2.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class MyViewPager2  extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public MyViewPager2(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

        switch (position){

            case 0: return FirstSemesterFragment.newInstance("first frag instance");
            case 1: return  SecondSemesterFragment.newInstance("second frag instance");
            case 2: return ThirdSemesterFragment.newInstance("third frag instance");
            case 3: return FourthSemesterFragment.newInstance("fourth frag instance");
            default: return FirstSemesterFragment.newInstance("first frag instance");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

FirstSemesterFragment.Java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FirstSemesterFragment extends Fragment {

    List<SemesterModelClass> mData;
    RVFragment adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private View view;

    public FirstSemesterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RVFragment(getContext(),mData);

        //this infaltes first semester fragment, viewpager2
        for (int i = 0; i < SemesterDataClass.courseCode1.length; i++) {
            mData.add(new SemesterModelClass(
                    SemesterDataClass.courseCode1[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.courseTitle1[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.creditUnit1[i]));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    public static FirstSemesterFragment newInstance(String text) {
        // i did not use this parameter
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FirstSemesterFragment fragment = new FirstSemesterFragment();
        args.putString("text",text);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

SecondSemesterFragment.Java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SecondSemesterFragment extends Fragment {
    List<SemesterModelClass> mData;
    RVFragment adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    View view;
    public SecondSemesterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RVFragment(getContext(),mData);

        //this inflates second semester fragment, viewpager2
        for (int i = 0; i < SemesterDataClass.courseCode2.length; i++) {
            mData.add(new SemesterModelClass(
                    SemesterDataClass.courseCode2[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.courseTitle2[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.creditUnit2[i]));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return  view;
    }
    public static SecondSemesterFragment newInstance(String text){
        // i did not use this parameter
        SecondSemesterFragment secondSemesterFragment = new SecondSemesterFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("text", text);
        secondSemesterFragment.setArguments(args);
        return secondSemesterFragment;
    }
}
```

ThirdSemesterFragment.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ThirdSemesterFragment extends Fragment {
    RVFragment adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<SemesterModelClass> mData;

    View view;

    public ThirdSemesterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RVFragment(getContext(),mData);

        //this inflates Third semester fragment, viewpager2
        for (int i = 0; i < SemesterDataClass.courseCode3.length; i++) {
            mData.add(new SemesterModelClass(
                    SemesterDataClass.courseCode3[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.courseTitle3[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.creditUnit3[i]));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    public static ThirdSemesterFragment newInstance(String text){
        // i did not use this parameter
        ThirdSemesterFragment thirdSemesterFragment = new ThirdSemesterFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("msg",text);
        thirdSemesterFragment.setArguments(args);
        return thirdSemesterFragment;
    }
}
```

FourthSemesterFragment.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FourthSemesterFragment extends Fragment {
RVFragment adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<SemesterModelClass> mData;

View view;
    public FourthSemesterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RVFragment(getContext(),mData);

        //this inflates Fourth semester fragment, viewpager2
        for (int i = 0; i < SemesterDataClass.courseCode4.length; i++) {
            mData.add(new SemesterModelClass(
                    SemesterDataClass.courseCode4[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.courseTitle4[i],
                    SemesterDataClass.creditUnit4[i]));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    public static FourthSemesterFragment newInstance(String text) {
        // i did not use this parameter
        FourthSemesterFragment fourthSemesterFragment = new FourthSemesterFragment();
        Bundle agrs = new Bundle();
        agrs.putString("msg",text);
        fourthSemesterFragment.setArguments(agrs);
        return fourthSemesterFragment;
    }
}
```

SemesterDataClass.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

public class SemesterDataClass {
    //Semester One Computer science
    static String[] courseCode1 = {"COM 101","COM 112", "COM 113","STA 111","STA 112", "MTH 111","MTH 112","GNS 102","GNS 127"};
    static String[] courseTitle1 = {"Intro to computing","intro to dig. elcnics","intro to progmmng","Descriptive Sta.","Elmtry probability",
                                  "Logic & Linear Algebra","Func. & Geometry","Comm. in englisg 1","Citizenship edu 1"};
    static String[] creditUnit1 = {"4","4","4","3","3","2","3","2","2"};

    //Semester Two Computer science
    static String[] courseCode2 = {"COM 121","COM 122", "COM 123","COM 124","COM 125", "COM 126","GNS 128","GNS 202"};
    static String[] courseTitle2 = {"Progmg using ooJava","Intro to the internet","Comp app packages I","Data struc. & algorithms","intro to syst analysis",
                                  "PC upgrade & maintenance","Comm. in englisg 1","Citizenship edu II"};
    static String[] creditUnit2 = {"6","4","6","4","3","6","2","2"};

    //Semester Three Computer science
    static String[] courseCode3 = {"COM 211","COM 212", "COM 213","COM 214","COM 215", "COM 216","BAM 126"};
    static String[] courseTitle3 = {"Progmg using ooBasic","Intro to syst progrmm","Unified Modeling lang(uml)","Filel org & mgmt","Comp packages II",
                                 "Comp syst trouble shooting I","Intro to entrepreneurship"};
    static String[] creditUnit3 = {"5","5","5","3","6","5","4"};

    //Semester Fourth Computer science
    static String[] courseCode4 = {"COM 222","COM 223", "COM 224","COM 225","COM 226", "COM 229","BAM 216"};
    static String[] courseTitle4 = {" Intro to scientific Prog Java","Seminar on comp & society","Basic hardware maintenance","Mgt info syst","Web technology",
                                   "Comp syst trouble shooting II","Project","Practice of entrepreneurship"};
    static String[] creditUnit4 = {"6","2","5","4","6","5","4","3"};
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:orientation="vertical"     tools:context=".MainActivity">      <FrameLayout         android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="match_parent"         android:id="@+id/frameLayout">      </FrameLayout>  </LinearLayout>
```

roww_xml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:orientation="horizontal"     android:layout_marginTop="5dp">      <TextView         android:id="@+id/tvSn"         android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"         android:paddingStart="5dp"         android:paddingLeft="5dp"         android:paddingRight="5dp"         android:text="@string/sn"         android:textSize="20sp"         android:textColor="@color/purple_200"/>      <TextView         android:id="@+id/tvCourseTitle"         android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"         android:paddingStart="5dp"         android:paddingLeft="5dp"         android:paddingRight="5dp"         android:text="@string/coursetitle"         android:textSize="20sp" />      <TextView         android:id="@+id/tvCourseCode"         android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"         android:paddingStart="5dp"         android:paddingLeft="5dp"         android:paddingRight="5dp"         android:text="@string/coursecode"         android:textSize="20sp" />      <TextView         android:id="@+id/tvCreditUnit"         android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"         android:paddingStart="5dp"         android:paddingLeft="5dp"         android:paddingRight="5dp"         android:text="@string/creditunit"         android:textColor="@color/purple_500"         android:textSize="20sp" /> </LinearLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:orientation="vertical">      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView         android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="match_parent"         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"         android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/> </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment_semester.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:orientation="vertical"     tools:context=".SemesterFragment" >       <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout         android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:id="@+id/tabLayout"/>      <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2         android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="match_parent"         android:id="@+id/viewPager2"/>  </LinearLayout>
```

fragment_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:layout_marginTop="60dp"     tools:context=".DepartmentFragment"     android:id="@+id/start_container"     android:orientation="horizontal">      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView         android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="match_parent"         android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>  </LinearLayout>
```

frame_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent">      <FrameLayout         android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="match_parent"         android:id="@+id/container_fragment">     </FrameLayout>   </LinearLayout>
```

row_department.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:background="@color/white">      <ImageView         android:layout_width="80dp"         android:layout_height="80dp"         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"         android:paddingTop="10dp"         android:paddingLeft="10dp"         android:id="@+id/imgDeptLogo"         android:paddingStart="10dp"         android:paddingEnd="10dp"         android:paddingRight="10dp"         android:contentDescription="@string/todoo" />      <TextView         android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:text="@string/department"         android:id="@+id/tvDepName"         android:textSize="24sp"         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"         android:paddingLeft="10dp"         android:paddingStart="10dp"         android:paddingEnd="10dp"         />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `How can I achieve` = what have you tried ?

Comment: That you're using ViewPager2 does not have much influence, you just need more screens than you first imagined. You either have 1 activity, that holds on to FragmentA that holds on to a ViewPager2 that holds on to FragmentA1 and FragmentA2. If item2 is clicked, then FragmentA is replaced by FragmentB. FragmentB holds on to a ViewPager2 that holds on to FragmentB1, FragmentB2 and FragmentB3

Comment: Or you have 2 activities, ActivityA that holds on to a ViewPager2 that holds on to FragmentA1 and FragmentA2. If item2 is clicked, then ActivityB is started. ActivityB holds on to a ViewPager2 that holds on to FragmentB1, FragmentB2 and FragmentB3

Comment: I have edited my code, please help

Comment: I have MainActivitity that hold list of departments(computer science and statistics), SemesterFragment that hold viewpager2, and the viewpager2 holding 4 frags (FirstSemesterFragment, SecondSemesterFragment,ThirdSemesterFragment and FourthSemesterFragment). When I click on item1 (I.e, computer science) in a recycler view It worked fine. Now I want to achieve that on click on Item2 (statistic) in a recycler view then I open ( another or thesame viewpager2 ??) But different Fragments in viewpager2, and continually because I have 10 Items to click in the recycler view. Thanks